# Meteor: How to clear imported css style in ES2015 modules

Tags: node.js, meteor, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am working on meteor project which has multiple layouts with different styles.

```
layoutSchool.scss
layoutCollege.scss
```

scss imported along with template render.

```
Template.layoutSchool.onCreated(function() {
  import '../styles/layoutSchool.scss';
});

Template.layoutCollege.onCreated(function() {
  import '../styles/layoutCollege.scss';
});
```

import statement creates `<style>` attributes under `<head>` tag. 
When I go to college template from school. school style still exists in college template.

How to clear existing imported style. Am I doing right approach?

Comment: I don't think you can clear them. As far as I know, you need to make sure that the various style sheets don't interfere with each other - part of the reason for using sass

Comment: Did you try to remove the previous style with JS in every Template...onCreate function? This could be done in jQuery tool.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned you have to remove them by yourself. You could do that in the `onDestroyed` calback. But I think a better aproach is to have just one `main' scss file that you will import just once and using a good naming convetion (http://thesassway.com/advanced/modular-css-naming-conventions) to avoid colisions.